# udev, how to prevent further rules to be run?

Tags: configuration, udev

Is it possible (and if so how) to tell udev to stop executing further rules for a certain device?

I know that there is an order/sequence of rules by the alphabetical naming of the udev files. Therefore it seems logical that earlier `*.rules` might want to prevent further (that is in the order later occuring rules) to be executed.

Let us assume I have a usb-memory-media which is via udev and its RUN+ script already mounted, I would dislike now that any other rule in the system tries (and probably fails) to yet again mount the device!

To facilitate responding I would like to also include an example:
Let the rule be like this:

```
# in file 30.myusb.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f75", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0902", RUN+="/bin/mount.30.1f75.0902.sh"
```

now I want this *further* (because of 31 > 30) rule not to happen

```
# in file 31.myusb.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f75", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0902", RUN+="/bin/mount.31.1f75.0902.sh"
```

the "filter" used to make **udev** able to tell if the rule applies is the same for both rules, yet I wished the 31.myusb.rules rule not ever to happen.

I am looking hence for a way to tweek `30.myusb.rules` in such a pseudo-code suggested way

```
# in file 30.myusb.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f75", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0902", RUN+="/bin/mount.30.1f75.0902.sh"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f75", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0902", STOP_FURTHER_RULES_WITH_THIS_FILTER
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `GOTO` in a rule to skip to a label as soon as the rule has been applied. If the label is at the very end of the rules, then all subsequent rules are skipped.

So in `30.myusb.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f75", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0902", RUN+="/bin/mount.30.1f75.0902.sh", GOTO="myusb_end"
```

And at the end of `31.myusb.rules`:

```
LABEL="myusb_end"
```

Or use `GOTO="very_end"`, and put `LABEL="very_end"` in a file that is loaded last (`/etc/udev/rules.d/zzzzzzzz.rules`).

Answer (score 4):

You must use **:=** instead of **+=**.

```
# in file 30.myusb.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f75", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0902", RUN:="/bin/mount.30.1f75.0902.sh"
```

From the *man* page,

> ```
>    "="
>        Assign a value to a key. Keys that represent a list are reset and
>        only this single value is assigned.
>
>    "+="
>        Add the value to a key that holds a list of entries.
>
>    ":="
>        Assign a value to a key finally; disallow any later changes.
> ```